# Can a nested object call a method from its nesting object?

Tags: python, object, nested

Considering two objects `A` and `B` with `B` nested in `A` as follows:

```
class Object_A:
    def __init__(self, nested_obj): 
        self.nested_obj = nested_obj
        
    def obj_A_do_domething(var): 
        var = var * 3
        return var
        

class Object_B : 
    def __init__(self, var): 
        self.x = 3
        
    def obj_B_make_A_do_domething(): 
        # how to call upper level obj here?
        pass    
        
objB = Object_B(var=3)
objA = Object_A(nested_obj=Object_B)

objA.nested_obj.obj_B_make_A_do_domething()
```

Can I call a method from a nesting object from the nested one?

Comment: It shouldn't. The need to do so usually results from poor design decisions.